# Struts2 Login/Register with facebook

Tags: java, facebook, struts2, restfb

I've recently found an open source library that does, post on a users facebook wall([restfb](http://restfb.com/) and [facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/))

All of them does the necessary things, but there's one thing left I need to do and that is to login and register users to my web application using their facebook account. are there any related frameworks for such task? if not, please provide alternative solutions

Comment: I think I did this a while back... if I recall the hard part (for me) was finding where to register my application and the proper settings to use on their page. The required code was pretty short and quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am correct in my understanding, all you want is to use Oauth or Open Id system to let user register and login to your website using Facebook or any other such service provider.

If i am correct in my understanding, there is a very good library which is quite easy to use and very light weight.

- [Scribe-Java](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)

It also contains few examples which shows how to use it and how it works, let us know if this is what you are looking.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct, I want the users to log in within our system using their facebook account. and also use their facebook account to register on our site. does the framework you provide fits the said needs?

Comment: this is perfect solution for you, its light weight and easy to use, also provides features for almost all platforms which provides Oauth service like Google,Yahoo,Twitter etc.Have a a look at the API and you will get a good idea.

Comment: so it also provides a "register with facebook" ?

Comment: "NO", i do not think such feature is provided by this, if i am correct Facebook SDK provide this feature,http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Comment: i have used that lib with 10+ applications and they all are working perfectely.